# Visual studio 2010 - make custom build script run always

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file

I have a .bat file I want to run everytime I build, it generates the build version.

I added it in "Custom build step" like:

```
call version.bat > $(SolutionDir)/version.h
```

and "output":

```
$(SolutionDir)/version.h
```

and it does this before BuildCompile.

But it only runs once... I suppose it somehow checks if version.h has changed or something - but I want this script to run everytime! What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Use a pre-build event rather than a custom build step